# Possible buffer overflow bug in std::use_facet::out()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, locale, buffer-overflow, codecvt

I think I have found a buffer overflow bug in the VC++10 std::locale object.  I would be grateful for second opinions as to whether I am doing something wrong.

The code below is simplified to demonstrate the problem.  I am trying to convert a wchar_t (UTF-16) character to the (Windows) ANSI code page 51949 (a.k.a. EUC-KR).  The code page was chosen because it uses double byte (DBCS) encoding.

I am deliberately supplying a single char buffer for a double byte result, expecting it to fail with a status of "partial" or "error".

Instead it is returning status "ok", writing past the end of the buffer and causing an exception for a corrupt stack when it tries to exit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <cwchar>

typedef std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t> cvt_t;

void PrintResult(cvt_t::result r)
{
    switch (r)
    {
        case cvt_t::ok: 
            std::cout << "ok\n";
            break;
        case cvt_t::partial: 
            std::cout << "partial\n";
            break;
        case cvt_t::error: 
            std::cout << "error\n";
            break;
        case cvt_t::noconv: 
            std::cout << "noconv\n";
            break;
    }
}
int main()
{
    const wchar_t src = L'안';
    char          dst = 0;
    std::locale   loc("Korean_Korea.51949");
    mbstate_t     state = { 0 };

    const cvt_t &facet = std::use_facet<cvt_t>(loc);
    cvt_t::result res;

    const wchar_t *pSrc;
    char *pDst;

    res = facet.out(state, &src, &src+1, pSrc, &dst, &dst+1, pDst);
    PrintResult(res);

    return 0;
}
```

Stepping inside facet.out() using the debugger, I find myself (down a couple of levels) in the following function:

```
virtual result __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL do_out(_Statype& _State,
    const _Elem *_First1, const _Elem *_Last1, const _Elem *& _Mid1,
        _Byte *_First2, _Byte *_Last2, _Byte *& _Mid2) const
    {   // convert [_First1, _Last1) to bytes [_First2, _Last)
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First1, _Last1);
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First2, _Last2);
    _Mid1 = _First1, _Mid2 = _First2;
    result _Ans = _Mid1 == _Last1 ? ok : partial;
    int _Bytes;

    while (_Mid1 != _Last1 && _Mid2 != _Last2)
        if ((int)MB_CUR_MAX <= _Last2 - _Mid2)
            if ((_Bytes = _Wcrtomb(_Mid2, *_Mid1,
                &_State, &_Cvt)) < 0)
                return (error); // locale-specific wcrtomb failed
            else
                ++_Mid1, _Mid2 += _Bytes, _Ans = ok;
        else
            {   // destination too small, convert into buffer
            _Byte _Buf[MB_LEN_MAX];
            _Statype _Stsave = _State;

            if ((_Bytes = _Wcrtomb(_Buf, *_Mid1,
                &_State, &_Cvt)) < 0)
                return (error); // locale-specific wcrtomb failed
            else if (_Last2 - _Mid2 < _Bytes)
                {   // converted too many, roll back and return previous
                _State = _Stsave;
                return (_Ans);
                }
            else
                {   // copy converted bytes from buffer
                _CSTD memcpy(_Mid2, _Buf, _Bytes);
                ++_Mid1, _Mid2 += _Bytes, _Ans = ok;
                }
            }
    return (_Ans);
    }
```

The problem seems to be this:

On the line `if ((int)MB_CUR_MAX <= _Last2 - _Mid2)`, MB_CURR_MAX (which is #defined to a function ___mb_cur_max_func(), is returning "1", not the "2" expected for a DBCS char.

```
_CRTIMP int __cdecl ___mb_cur_max_func(void)
{
    /*
     * Note that we don't need _LocaleUpdate in this function.
     * The main reason being, that this is a leaf function in
     * locale usage terms.
     */
    _ptiddata ptd = _getptd();
    pthreadlocinfo ptloci = ptd->ptlocinfo;

    __UPDATE_LOCALE(ptd, ptloci);

    return ptloci->mb_cur_max;
}
```

This function seems to be accessing a global locale, rather than the locale that was supplied when initialising the facet.

If I set the global locale as follows:

```
std::locale::global(loc);
```

It all works OK (and fails with status "partial").

Thus it seems to me that this particular implementation of `out()` is incorrectly using the global locale to determine MB_CUR_MAX, instead of the locale supplied at the object's construction -- and thus causing a buffer overflow bug.

Anybody able to point out my mistake(s) in this?

### ------------------------------
Update 20 May 2013
------------------------------

I have reported this to MS as bug 787227.

See http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/787227/buffer-overflow-bug-in-std-use-facet-out

### ------------------------------
Update 27 July 2015
------------------------------

I have an email from Microsoft saying that this bug is fixed in the new RTM of Visual Studio 2015.  (Yay)

Comment: Oops!  Accidentally posted this before completing.  Edit to finish it will follow in 10 or 20 minutes.

Comment: I can confirm that this behavior is still present in VC++ 2012.